# Align recyclerview item to Top when there is only one content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

My recycler view implementation seems to align properly to the top if the data source contains more than one data, but with only one data the item centers vertically.

How can I prevent this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent""
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listview_jobs_list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="top"
            />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you might give height to your recyclerView "match_parent" and to your ConstraintLayout "wrap_content". by this your recyclerView will set its height to LinearLayout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listview_jobs_list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="top"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

try this and let me know about the result

Comment: matching a parent that is wrapping its content creates an infinite loop and the Android will break down with sparks and smoke, well it isn't the right thing to do in layouts.